# Django User Database Implementation

Tags: python, mysql, django

quick question. I'm playing with Django and mysql. So say I have different societies, each with a sign up page, and lets say a user is able to join multiple societies, how can I be able to see in my database, how many/which societies the user is signed up to? (I was thinking maybe if I could use a field in the database that has a list/array datatype. That would be so convenient. But no such datatype exists. Or maybe a textfield and append to it every new society id that a user joins. Not sure.)

Comment: Hi Grudge, have you got any code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: I suggest you to create Society and User models. Post that code here and we can help you with next steps.

Comment: If you are using a relational database, then pls think about relational database solutions first. Storing a list of values in a field breaks the relational database design. See the answers to the following question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: @shadow you're right. I think i'll just settle for a many to many relationship between my society and user models, then if I want to know which societies a user has joined, i'll just perfom a query.